# How to find the principal axis of a blob which goes through the centroid of the blob?

Tags: python, opencv, blob, axis, centroid

I want to find the principal axis of a blob which goes through the centroid of the blob. I was able to find the centroid of the blob, but how can I find the principal axis?

Here's what I have tried:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('skin6.jpg')

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(imgray, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

#find the maximum contour
contours, heir = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

tmpArea = np.zeros(img.shape)
cv2.drawContours(tmpArea,[c],0,(255, 255, 255),cv2.FILLED)

#centroid
M = cv2.moments(c)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

cv2.circle(tmpArea, (cx, cy), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow("tmpArea", tmpArea)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

These are the images that I used:

[image]

[image: Image2]

I'm expecting something like this. It should connect with the contour properly:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISWli.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cv2.fitEllipse`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa) on your detected contour. [There's an OpenCV tutorial on that topic.](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) You get the center of the fitted ellipse, the length of both axes (please have a detailed look at [`cv2.ellipse`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69)), and the rotation angle. From that information, it's just some math to get the principal axis through the center.

Here's your code with some modifications and additions:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Images
img = cv2.imread('images/1KXQA.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
tmpArea = np.zeros(img.shape)

# Contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(tmpArea,[c],0,(255, 255, 255),cv2.FILLED)

# Centroid
M = cv2.moments(c)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
cv2.circle(tmpArea, (cx, cy), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

# Ellipse
e = cv2.fitEllipse(c)
cv2.ellipse(tmpArea, e, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Principal axis
x1 = int(np.round(cx + e[1][1] / 2 * np.cos((e[2] + 90) * np.pi / 180.0)))
y1 = int(np.round(cy + e[1][1] / 2 * np.sin((e[2] + 90) * np.pi / 180.0)))
x2 = int(np.round(cx + e[1][1] / 2 * np.cos((e[2] - 90) * np.pi / 180.0)))
y2 = int(np.round(cy + e[1][1] / 2 * np.sin((e[2] - 90) * np.pi / 180.0)))
cv2.line(tmpArea, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 0), 2)

# Output
cv2.imshow('tmpArea', tmpArea)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
NumPy:         1.19.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there are asymmetric skin lesions in my data set, so it will not work for those images. Is there another way to get the principal axis? @HansHirse

Comment: @NaduniJayaweera Then please add additional images to your question showing the desired principal axis, maybe manually drawn into. For the second, newly provided image, I'm not sure, what you want to have as the final result.

Comment: Added the expected output @HansHirse

Comment: @NaduniJayaweera Unfortunately, that image itself is not very helpful, since there's no description, what the principal axis actually is. Yes, it's the blue line with the angle theta, but what's the definition, how is that blue line obtained? And, what would be the corresponding blue line in your examples? Please draw those into your images, and provide a proper description for the principle axis.