# OpenCV, how to find bounding rect with max height/width ratio

Tags: opencv

I have some leaf images.

[image]

the red rectangle comes from `cv2.minAreaRect`, while the green one is what I actually want.

I want a bounding rect with max height/width ratio.

I know I can rotate this image 1 degree by 1 degree, calculate `cv2.boundingRect` each time and find the one with  max height/width ratio. But it is slow and seems not really necessary.

Anyone can help me to find a more graceful solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can address this problem, but what you are aiming to do is to find the principle axis or the main axis(length of your rectangle):

1. Using [cv2.fitEllipse](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa) on your detected contour, from that information, it's just some math to get the principal axis through the center. You can find sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806758/how-to-find-the-principal-axis-of-a-blob-which-goes-through-the-centroid-of-the#:%7E:text=import%20cv2%0Aimport%20numpy%20as%20np%0A%0A%23%20Images,cv2.imshow(%27tmpArea%27%2C%20tmpArea)%0Acv2.waitKey(0)) and you can rotate your image based on the orientation of the major axis.
2. You can use [Contour Properties](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html) to find the [orientation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html#:%7E:text=5.-,Orientation,-Orientation%20is%20the) of the threshold blob . Orientation is the angle at which object is directed. Following method also gives the Major Axis and Minor Axis lengths. Use the angle to rotate your image.

```py
(x,y),(MA,ma),angle = cv.fitEllipse(cnt)
```